# Verb-ing without be but not gerund

Tags: grammar

> The suit was altered superbly by the tailor, making the timid old man feel like a bold young lion.

I don't understand why the sentence is correct because the word "making" isn't placed after a form of 'be'. But I think it's not a gerund, and I think the word "was" in the beginning of the sentence is for the "altered superbly by the tailor". Please help me to understand the grammar involved here.

Comment: It doesn't need "be". "Making" is a verb heading the non-finite gerund-participial clause "making the timid old man feel ...". The clause functions as a result adjunct, here a supplement prosodically detached and set apart in writing by a comma. Semantically, it is similar to a supplementary relative clause, cf. "..., which made the timid old man feel like ..."

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613256/2085).

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> It doesn't need "be". "Making" is a verb heading the non-finite gerund-participial clause "making the timid old man feel ...". The clause functions as a result adjunct, here a supplement prosodically detached and set apart in writing by a comma. Semantically, it is similar to a supplementary relative clause, cf. "..., which made the timid old man feel like ..."